# How to clear kendo window data using refresh method?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have form and grid in kendo window modal, I want to refresh the screen everytime user open the modal window, I have used `refresh()` but its not working...any suggetion will be appreciated....

So far tried code...

main.html

```
<div kendo-window="viewAttestorkWin" options="attWinOptions" k-modal="true"></div>
```

main.js

```
$scope.openAttestorSearch = function(){
          $scope.viewAttestorkWin.refresh();
          attestorConfig.attestorModalWinConfig.title = 'Add Attestor(s)';
          $scope.viewAttestorkWin.setOptions(attestorConfig.attestorModalWinConfig);
          $scope.viewAttestorkWin.open().center();

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work properly with your code right now, yet I suspect `setOptions` make it didn't. Have you try to call the refresh method after window is open?

```
$scope.openAttestorSearch = function(){
    attestorConfig.attestorModalWinConfig.title = 'Add Attestor(s)';
    $scope.viewAttestorkWin.setOptions(attestorConfig.attestorModalWinConfig);
    $scope.viewAttestorkWin.refresh().center().open();
};
```